# Problem of transmission of a variable from a function to another function in the same controller

Tags: php, function, controller, laravel-8

being a beginner in laravel I am stuck on a problem. I need to recover a variable named $id3 which is in the index function, to use it in another function named recup. Then I want to use it in an sql request, but I'm stuck on the fact to pass the variable from one function to another.

Here are the two functions that are in the controller :

```
public function index(Request $request, Groupecampagne $id_campagne, Groupe $groupes)
    {

        $groupes = Groupe::all()->get('groupes.*');
        $groupecampagnes = Groupecampagne::join('campagnes', 'campagnes.id_campagne', '=', 'campagne_groupe.id_campagne')
            ->get(['campagne_groupe.*', 'campagnes.id_campagne']);
        $segs = DB::table('segements')->select('segements.nom_segment', 'segements.id_segment')
            ->get();
        $cpgrps = DB::table('campagne_groupe')->select('campagne_groupe.statut_publication')
            ->groupby('campagne_groupe.statut_publication')
            ->get('campagne_groupe');

        return view('groupecampagnes.index', compact('groupecampagnes', 'segs', 'cpgrps', 'id_campagne', 'groupes'))
            ->with('i', (request()->input('page', 1) - 1) * 5);
        session(['id_campagne' => 'value']);             

        $id2 = $request->fullUrl();
        return $id3 = substr($id2, 38, 3);
    }

public function recup(Request $request, $id3)
    {
        $valeur = $request->input('id_segment');
        DB::insert('INSERT INTO segment_groupe (id_groupe, id_segment)
                    SELECT groupes.id_groupe, segements.id_segment
                    FROM groupes JOIN segment_groupe JOIN segements
                    ON groupes.id_groupe = segment_groupe.id_groupe
                    AND segment_groupe.id_segment = segements.id_segment
                    WHERE segment_groupe.id_segment =' . $valeur);

        DB::insert('INSERT INTO campagne_groupe (id_groupe, id_campagne)
                    SELECT segment_groupe.id_groupe, ' . $id3 . '
                    FROM segment_groupe JOIN campagne_groupe JOIN campagnes
                    ON segment_groupe.id_groupe = campagne_groupe.id_groupe
                    AND campagne_groupe.id_campagne = campagnes.id_campagne
                    WHERE segment_groupe.id_segment =' . $valeur);
        
    }
```

I've already tried what I could find on the net, and I can't find any document that could help me.

Comment: you can't access variables from other functions like this. you have to declare the public variable like public $id3 = ''; in the controller class. then you can read or write this variable as $this->id3  variable.

Comment: Or, in this particular instance - have the `index` method itself execute the `recup` method ...

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I will test it and I will keep you informed.

Comment: I tried with $this->id3, but I got nothing. How would you have coded it? Or just an example, just to inspire me.

Comment: In fact the recup function is only executed when a button is pressed, at least that's what I'm trying to do. And so if it's the index function that executes recup, I won't be able to use the recup function for my button since it will be missing a value in the sql request. 
After I say that, maybe it's possible to do it anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I update the solution adding a new function that insert and inside recup I only let the capture of the parameters, I saw that you have a button that call the recup function, so this can work for you.

Also you can see that the new function only have the task of insert and this receive the parameters that you need.

```
public function index(Request $request, Groupecampagne $id_campagne, Groupe $groupes)
{
    $groupes = Groupe::all()->get('groupes.*');
    $groupecampagnes = Groupecampagne::join('campagnes', 'campagnes.id_campagne', '=', 'campagne_groupe.id_campagne')->get(['campagne_groupe.*', 'campagnes.id_campagne']);
    $segs = DB::table('segements')->select('segements.nom_segment', 'segements.id_segment')->get();
    $cpgrps = DB::table('campagne_groupe')->select('campagne_groupe.statut_publication')->groupby('campagne_groupe.statut_publication')->get('campagne_groupe');

    return view('groupecampagnes.index', compact('groupecampagnes', 'segs', 'cpgrps', 'id_campagne', 'groupes'))
        ->with('i', (request()->input('page', 1) - 1) * 5);
    session(['id_campagne' => 'value']);             
}


public function recup(Request $request)
{
    $idSegment = $request->input('id_segment');

    $id2 = $request->fullUrl();
    $id3 = substr($id2, 38, 3);
    
    $insert = $this->insert($idSegment, $id3);
}

public function insert($idSegment, $id3)
{
    DB::insert('INSERT INTO segment_groupe (id_groupe, id_segment)
                SELECT groupes.id_groupe, segements.id_segment
                FROM groupes JOIN segment_groupe JOIN segements
                ON groupes.id_groupe = segment_groupe.id_groupe
                AND segment_groupe.id_segment = segements.id_segment
                WHERE segment_groupe.id_segment =' . $idSegment);

    DB::insert('INSERT INTO campagne_groupe (id_groupe, id_campagne)
                SELECT segment_groupe.id_groupe, ' . $id3 . '
                FROM segment_groupe JOIN campagne_groupe JOIN campagnes
                ON segment_groupe.id_groupe = campagne_groupe.id_groupe
                AND campagne_groupe.id_campagne = campagnes.id_campagne
                WHERE segment_groupe.id_segment =' . $idSegment);
}
```

I hope this help you!
Try it!

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I will try, I will let you know if it works.

Comment: I tested it and it returns an error on the first variable I need because the value is not transmitted.

Comment: I edit the solution, try it!

Comment: I put the variables ($id2, $id3) inside the recup because the view index only must have static parameters that you need to show in the view.

Comment: I will try, I will let you know if it works.

Comment: Thanks for your help, it didn't work.

Comment: $id2 = $request->fullUrl();
 $id3 = substr($id2, 38, 3);   This piece of code must stay in the index function to retrieve what I'm interested in, otherwise it retrieves something else I don't need.

Comment: What do you need and what are you receiving?

Comment: it retrieves a data contained in a string url, that's why I cut the part I need from the url I retrieve, to then use it in an sql query, and it's only in the index function, because it's linked to the session element.

Comment: shouldn't be a problem, you could get the url inside the recup method.

Comment: write below $id3 variable for see what are you are getting:

dd($id3);

Comment: You also can modified the substr for example: ($id2, 30, 3)

Comment: I can't recover it in recup, because it recovers something else entirely, and so the value I need is not present. And it's the same for modifying it, I've already done some tests with this variable to see what I get, and everything is fine. Now I just have to find a way to use this value in recup without moving the code that allows me to have the value I want.

Comment: Can you send the value that you need in the same way that you send id_segment?

Comment: I don't see how to send it the same way. The id_segment is retrieved from a selection dropdown, whose selected value is sent only after a button click, because it is in a form. And the second value I need is in the url that comes from session. And the url of the session changes with each action performed.

Comment: mmm, I need more detail for help you